# CSS: On Ice Cream Sandwich Browser, media query no longer working

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an HTC Evo 3D.  When my phone was running Gingerbread, if I accessed the [Leicester City Council Website](http://www.leicester.gov.uk/) using my phone, it would respect load CSS link elements such as below:

```
<link href="mobile.css"  
      media="only screen and (max-device-width: 520px)" 
      type="text/css" 
      rel="stylesheet" />
```

(These same link elements would be ignored by desktop browsers.)

Since I upgraded to Ice Cream Sandwich, css link elements such as the above do not get loaded.  The result is that the website looks the same as the desktop version.

Is there anything I can do to make css links such as the one above, work for ICS's browser?

**EDIT :** Since working on this, I have found out that Chrome on ICS works as expected so I will be using this for mobile testing for now.

Answer (score 1):

Android added option to view either desktop or mobile version of site in ICS.
Did you tried unchecking "View desktop site" from settings (second menu button)?

For more details on this, google with "ICS browser view desktop version"

Comment: On my browser settings, this was unchecked and it still does not load the CSS.